# C# - OleDB Systax Error in From Clause

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I am using Microsoft Access to create a "Desktop Database" and saved it as "new.mdb" into my C# Debug folder.

However, upon using the SELECT statement, my C# project throws an Exception.

This is my database
[image]

And this is my code

```
   conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=new.mdb");
            conn.Open();
            dataset = new DataSet();
            string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM User";
            dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStatement, conn);
            oOrderDetailsCmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dbAdapter);
            dbAdapter.Fill(dataset);
            contactsTab = dataset.Tables[0];
            contactsTab.TableName = "User";
            rows = contactsTab.Rows;
```

The error upon executing that code is

`Syntax error in FROM clause.`

[image]

However, the query looks fine. Is there anything wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT :**

`OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` (Example : Creating new table) works for this. I'm not sure why SELECT statement doesn't :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User is a reserved keyword in SQL. So write SQL like below

```
 string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM [User]";
```

Comment: Wow..can't believe it. Works! But I have another question. So if I have to use the `[]` in this question, what about others? Like `contactsTab.TableName = "User";`  and inserting of new rows `DataRow uTabRow = dataset.Tables["User"].NewRow();`. Do I need them too?

Comment: User is keyword in SQL only. not in dataset. Whenever writing an TSQL statement check for these kind of keywords. The above error was from DB not from c#. @user2301818 Mark as answer if my answer helped you. Thanks